# Scrapy (Python): Iterating over 'next' page without multiple functions

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to grab stock data from Yahoo! Finance.

Sometimes, I need to loop over several pages, 19 in [this example](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=PWF.TO&a=04&b=19&c=2005&d=04&e=19&f=2010&g=d&z=66&y=132) , in order to get all of the stock data.

Previously (when I knew there would only be two pages), I would use one function for each page, like so:

```
def stocks_page_1(self, response):

    returns_page1 = []

    #Grabs data here...

    current_page = response.url
    next_page = current_page + "&z=66&y=66"
    yield Request(next_page, self.stocks_page_2, meta={'returns_page1': returns_page1})

def stocks_page_2(self, response):

    # Grab data again...
```

Now, instead of writing 19 or more functions, I was wondering if there was a way I could loop through an iteration using one function to grab all data from all pages available for a given stock.

Something like this:

```
        for x in range(30): # 30 was randomly selected
            current_page = response.url
            # Grabs Data
            # Check if there is a 'next' page:
            if response.xpath('//td[@align="right"]/a[@rel="next"]').extract() != ' ': 
                u = x * 66
                next_page = current_page + "&z=66&y={0}".format(u)
                # Go to the next page somehow within the function???
```

**Updated Code:**

Works, but only returns one page of data.

```
class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):


name = "dnot"
allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com", "http://eoddata.com/"]
start_urls = ['http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT']
rules = [
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//td[@align="right"]/a[@rel="next"]'),
     callback='stocks1',
     follow=True),
]
def stocks1(self, response):
        returns = []
        rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]//table/tr')[1:]
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
            try:
                values = cells[-1]
                try:
                    float(values)
                    returns.append(values)
                except ValueError:
                    continue
            except ValueError:
                continue  

        unformatted_returns = response.meta.get('returns_pages')
        returns = [float(i) for i in returns]
        global required_amount_of_returns, counter
        if counter == 1 and "CAT" in response.url:
            required_amount_of_returns = len(returns)
        elif required_amount_of_returns == 0:
            raise CloseSpider("'Error with initiating required amount of returns'")

        counter += 1
        print counter

        # Iterator to calculate Rate of return 
        # ====================================
        if data_intervals == "m": 
            k = 12
        elif data_intervals == "w":
            k = 4
        else: 
            k = 30

        sub_returns_amount = required_amount_of_returns - k
        sub_returns = returns[:sub_returns_amount]
        rate_of_return = []

        if len(returns) == required_amount_of_returns or "CAT" in response.url:
            for number in sub_returns:
                numerator = number - returns[k]
                rate = numerator/returns[k]
                if rate == '': 
                    rate = 0
                rate_of_return.append(rate)
                k += 1

        item = Website()
        items = []
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/h2/text()').extract()
        item['avg_returns'] = numpy.average(rate_of_return)
        item['var_returns'] = numpy.cov(rate_of_return)
        item['sd_returns'] = numpy.std(rate_of_return)
        item['returns'] = returns
        item['rate_of_returns'] = rate_of_return
        item['exchange'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="rtq_exch"]/text()').extract()
        item['ind_sharpe'] = ((numpy.average(rate_of_return) - RFR) / numpy.std(rate_of_return))
        items.append(item)
        yield item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see, a parse callback is just a function that takes the response and returns or yields either `Item`s or `Request`s or both. There is no issue at all with reusing these callbacks, so you can just pass the same callback for every request.

Now, you *could* pass the current page info using the `Request` meta but instead, I'd leverage the `CrawlSpider` to crawl across every page. It's really easy, start generating the `Spider` with the command line:

```
scrapy genspider --template crawl finance finance.yahoo.com
```

Then write it like this:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
```

Scrapy 1.0 has deprecated the `scrapy.contrib` namespace for the modules above, but if you're stuck with 0.24, use `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors` and `scrapy.contrib.spiders`.

```
from yfinance.items import YfinanceItem


class FinanceSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'finance'
    allowed_domains = ['finance.yahoo.com']
    start_urls = ['http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=PWF.TO&a=04&b=19&c=2005&d=04&e=19&f=2010&g=d&z=66&y=132']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='[rel="next"]'),
             callback='parse_items',
             follow=True),
    )
```

`LinkExtractor` will pick up the links in the response to follow, but it can be limited with XPath (or CSS) and regular expressions. See [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml) for more.

`Rule`s will follow the links and call the `callback` on every response. `follow=True` will keep extracting links on every new response, but it can be limited by depth. See [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) again.

```
    def parse_items(self, response):
        for line in response.css('.yfnc_datamodoutline1 table tr')[1:-1]:
            yield YfinanceItem(date=line.css('td:first-child::text').extract()[0])
```

Just yield the `Item`s, since `Request`s for the next pages will be handled by the `CrawlSpider` `Rule`s.

Comment: What if instead of `YfinanceItem` I wanted to put the values into `item['returns']`?

Comment: I have no idea how this saves all of the returns in a proper chronological order, for all pages. How can I then get these values in another function?

Comment: Ordering items is up to you. You can read the date and turn it into a unix timestamp, to make ordering easier.

Comment: How do I take the stock prices and use them in another function with this method? Before I would pass a list of the returns from `def stocks1` (where the prices where gathered) to another function `finalize_stock` which would gather all the data for that stock. How can I do the same here?

Comment: Please see updated code in the question. I cut everything down to one function, but and am using the rule like you suggested, but it still only grabs data from one page?